# Update connection state in with blazor components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I implemented Blazor components in my ASP.NET Core MVC application to perform tasks more dynamically, however, I needed to get the user logged in and redirect if he is no longer logged in, and I managed as follows:

```cs
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authProvider;
@code{
    private AuthenticationState _auth;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authStateProvider = (AuthenticationStateProvider)_authProvider;
        authStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += HandleAuthenticationStateChanged;
        await ReloadRequestAuthorization();
    }

    private async void HandleAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        _auth = await task;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    public void Action(){
        Console.WriteLine(_auth.User.Identity.GetId());
    }
}
```

But, if I finish my `authentication`, this `'connected'` state doesn't change, it stays connected even if I end the session.

How do I make this state change in case the logged in user is knocked out/logged out?

Comment: Your `HandleAuthenticationStateChanged` doesn't do anything other than render the component (which you don't show us so ?? ).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I used another method to perform what I need.

In my login controller, I added the method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> IsAuthenticated()
    => Ok(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
```

I created a JavaScript function:

```js
  async function isAuth() {
    const result = await $.ajax({
        url: '/isAuth'
    }).done(function (r) {
        console.log(r);
        return r;
    }).fail(function (r) {
        console.log('not authenticated')
        return false;
    })
    return result;
}
```

And in Blazor:

```cs
bool result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>('isAuth');
```

If I remove the authentication cookie, or end the session, the JS return is always updated!